# Fluid dynamics and Bernoulli equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, definition, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

What is the basic difference between static, dynamic and hydrostatic head in bernolli equation?

---

Is static pressure gauge pressure or thermodynamic pressure?